# How to enable close button on custom dialog in WiX installer

Tags: dialog, wix, window, cancel-button

Creating a custom dialog with WiX Toolset 3.8., I struggled to enable the close button of the dialog, and while I found some hints on the web, there was no clean answer anywhere. Adding this question for the sake of the next person to have the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog needs to contain a control with `Cancel="yes"`, this seems to be tied to the enabled state of the window close button.

```
<Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Cancel" Cancel="yes" />
```

[image]

Comment: Hitting this button (or closing the dialog) throws an error with code 2228 for me.

Answer (score 2):

you also need the "EndDialog" event with the "Return" value

```
<Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Cancel" Cancel="yes" >
  <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
</Control>
```